# How to iterate HashMap of ArrayList in Java 8 with streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following data set with Key is String and value as List of values.

I wanted to call a method with key and each value of list as parameters to the method. Iterate for all the keys. I am able to do it with two forEach loops as shown in my example below. 
I would like know if we can write the same logic using streams and flatMap in Java 8 without forEach inner loop? thanks

```
Map<String,ArrayList<String>> xhashMap ;

if(xhashMap!=null)  {

 xhashMap.forEach((k,l)-> {

    if(k.equals("ax")){
           l.forEach(v->{
            method1(v,AA.class);
           }
     }
    if(k.equals("bx")){
           l.forEach(v->{
            method1(v,BB.class);
           }
     }

  });

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a Stream for this? It seems like a Stream implementation will be more confusing; especially as you're mapping to different class types.

Comment: i thought if we have large set of data streams would perform well in this case. But I am not sure. So just checking. You think I am doing correctly and it can not be done in streams. I don't have experience with streams API. Just started learning

Comment: Seeing as you're seeding your data from a Map that is already in memory, it's likely not going to be any better to use a Stream - what you have above is probably the better way.

Comment: Ok thanks for your input.

Comment: Why are you iterating over the map to find specific keys?  `map.getOrDefault("ax", emptyList()).forEach(v -> method1(v, AA.class))` or, if missing key is an exceptional condition, simply `map.get("ax").forEach(...)`

Comment: @Misha, yes, you are right, that's right approach. thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you use a `for` loop, `forEach` or the `Stream` API. In all cases, you are iterating over a `Map` to compare each key against a certain value, which is perverting the concept of maps, to associate the key with a value and provide (usually far better that linear) lookup methods.

Further, you should use a `Map<String, List<String>>` instead, not referring to an *implementation* type like `ArrayList`, and not letting it be `null` in the first place, instead of having it to check for `null` later-on.

If you follow theses advice, your code becomes

```
Map<String, List<String>> xhashMap;
// always initialize the map to a non-null reference

xhashMap.getOrDefault("ax", Collections.emptyList())
        .forEach(v -> method1(v, AA.class));
xhashMap.getOrDefault("bx", Collections.emptyList())
        .forEach(v -> method1(v, BB.class));
```

If the map is, as the variable name suggests, a hash map, the two lookups will have `O(1)` time complexity, but even a `TreeMap` with `O(log(n))` complexity will be better than iterating over the map and compare all keys.

As long as the action consists of a sole method invocation with different parameters, there is not much gain in trying to re-use common code, as the sharing code would be much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can't write it with Stream API, but it's not much better.

Since you are performing side effects and not collecting results, `Stream` would essentially be:

```
xhashMap.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .forEach(e -> ...);
```

and unfortunately, contain same logic inside the `forEach`.

Actually, you can even skip `Stream` creation at this point because you can perform `forEach` without creating a `Stream`:

```
xhashMap.entrySet()
  .forEach(e -> ...);
```

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz, I agree. we don't need stream now. Your statement .entryset().forEach(e->...) . again I have to check below based on key the second parameter will change in my case. for example in case of key "ax" it will be AA.class,. so that's why I have to check the key value explicitly.

Comment: @techi e is an Entry and it contains both Key and Value - essentially it's not really better than your solution

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can be done with flatMap and closures

```
xHashMap.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        .<Runnable>map(v -> () -> {
                            final String k = e.getKey();
                            if (k.equals("ax")) {
                                method1(v, AA.class);
                            }
                            if (k.equals("bx")) {
                                method1(v, BB.class);
                            }
                        })
                )
                .forEach(Runnable::run);
```